# How to create a tree structure with spring data jpa？

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created a spring boot project and want to use spring-data-jpa to implement a categorized list of tree structures like this

```
+ **所有分类**
|---低值消耗品
|       |-------二极管
|       |-------导线
|       |-------网线
|---非低值消耗品
|       |-------路由器
...
```

So I tried to implement it using @manytoone and @onetomany annotations.

I created an Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Slf4j
    @Data
    @Table(name = "bs_dev_category")
    public class BSDevCategory extends BaseEntity {

        public BSDevCategory() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="CAT_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="CAT_PARENT_ID",referencedColumnName = "CAT_ID")   //
        private BSDevCategory parent;

        @Column(name="CAT_NAME", nullable=false, length=50)
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
        private Set children = new LinkedHashSet(0);

    }
```

I also created a test class for it.

```
    @SpringBootTest
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class BSDevCategoryRepositoryTest {

        @Autowired
        private BSDevCategoryRepository bsDevCategoryRepository;

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BSDevCategoryRepositoryTest.class);

        @Test
        public void save() throws Exception{
            BSDevCategory bsDevCategory = new BSDevCategory();
            bsDevCategory.setId(6);
            BSDevCategory bsDevCategory1 = new BSDevCategory();
            bsDevCategory1.setName("非低值易耗品");
            bsDevCategory1.setParent(bsDevCategory);
            this.bsDevCategoryRepository.save(bsDevCategory1);
        }

        @Test
        @Transactional
        //I added  @Transactional to avoid no session exception
        public void get() throws Exception{

            Optional bsDevCategoryOpt = this.bsDevCategoryRepository.findById(7);
            BSDevCategory bsDevCategory = bsDevCategoryOpt.get();
            logger.info("name={}",bsDevCategory.getName());
            logger.info("id={}",bsDevCategory.getId());
            logger.info("createtime={}",bsDevCategory.getCreateTime());
            logger.info("updatetime={}",bsDevCategory.getUpdateTime());

            //logger.info("all={}",this.bsDevCategoryRepository.findAll());
            BSDevCategory bsDevCategory1 = bsDevCategory.getParent();

            logger.info("parent name={}",bsDevCategory1.getName());
            logger.info("parent id={}",bsDevCategory1.getId());
            logger.info("parent createtime={}",bsDevCategory1.getCreateTime());
            logger.info("parent updatetime={}",bsDevCategory1.getUpdateTime());

            //Set bsDevCategories = bsDevCategory.getChildren();
            Set children = bsDevCategory.getChildren();//The program crashes when it runs here
            Iterator it = children.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                BSDevCategory  bsDevCategory2 = it.next();
                logger.info("child name={}",bsDevCategory2.getName());
                logger.info("child id={}",bsDevCategory2.getId());
                logger.info("child createtime={}",bsDevCategory2.getCreateTime());
                logger.info("child updatetime={}",bsDevCategory2.getUpdateTime());
            }


        }
    }
```

Then I started to run the save method in the BSDevCategoryRepositoryTest.class.
It work's for me and saved some data in the database.
[data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeV5y.png)

But when I execute the get method, I get errors:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
>               at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:155)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:268)
>           at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
>           at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.getName(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
>           at com.osneix.devmgt.Repository.BSDevCategoryRepositoryTest.get(BSDevCategoryRepositoryTest.java:56)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>           at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Then I searched for solutions on the Internet and finally found four solutions.

1. I Changed the `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` to `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`,but it doesn't work for me.
2. I added ·spring.jpa.open-in-view=true· to `application.properties`,but it doesn't work for me.

3.I added `@Transactional` before `public void get() throws Exception{`,it works!

4.I added 'spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true' in `application.properties`,it works for me.

Through 3 and 4, I can avoid the no session exception, but when executing to getChildren () method, the console will appear much more than expected SQL statement until the last program Stack Overflow abnormal termination

[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImkiT.png)

The information that appears in the console at this time is as follows:

```
    ...Ignored many sql statements here...

    Hibernate: select children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_1_, children0_.create_time as create_t2_0_1_, children0_.update_time as update_t3_0_1_, children0_.cat_name as cat_name4_0_1_, children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_1_ from bs_dev_category children0_ where children0_.cat_parent_id=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_1_, children0_.create_time as create_t2_0_1_, children0_.update_time as update_t3_0_1_, children0_.cat_name as cat_name4_0_1_, children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_1_ from bs_dev_category children0_ where children0_.cat_parent_id=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_1_, children0_.create_time as create_t2_0_1_, children0_.update_time as update_t3_0_1_, children0_.cat_name as cat_name4_0_1_, children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_1_ from bs_dev_category children0_ where children0_.cat_parent_id=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_1_, children0_.create_time as create_t2_0_1_, children0_.update_time as update_t3_0_1_, children0_.cat_name as cat_name4_0_1_, children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_1_ from bs_dev_category children0_ where children0_.cat_parent_id=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_0_, children0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_1_, children0_.create_time as create_t2_0_1_, children0_.update_time as update_t3_0_1_, children0_.cat_name as cat_name4_0_1_, children0_.cat_parent_id as cat_pare5_0_1_ from bs_dev_category children0_ where children0_.cat_parent_id=?

    ...Ignored many sql statements here...

    ...Ignored so many log statements here...

    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6d17914a
    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@49631cfb
    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@77b71c9
    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6133e20b
    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@30ffb2a6
    2018-04-19 17:57:05.198  WARN 780 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@612af486

    ...Ignored so many log statements here...

    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:439)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:761)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4025)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:190)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.hashCode(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.hashCode(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.hashCode(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.hashCode(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2184)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:84)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.hashCode(BSDevCategory_$$_jvst204_0.java)
        at com.osneix.devmgt.Entity.BSDevCategory.hashCode(BSDevCategory.java:25)

    ....
```

I didn't know where goes wrong,and how to fix it.

Comment: Please use standard English, so that we can help you.